# How to reactivate user django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm currently having troubles in setting `is_active` field from `False` back to `True` in Django. I have a custom Account model which is inhereted from `AbstractBaseUser` and is managed by `class AccountManager(BaseUserManager)`.

By default, I override the `is_active` field to be False. However, when I try to reactivate the field again. It does update at that time in `python manage.py shell`, but when I logout and login back to the shell. The `is_active` field is still `False`. Below is my `activateUser()` function

```
def activateUser(self, account):
    account.is_active = True
    account.save()

    return account
```

Below is my `python manage.py shell` perform:

```
>>> from authentication.models import Account
>>> a = Account.objects.all()[0]
>>> a.is_active
False
>>> Account.objects.activateUser(a)
>>> a.is_active
True
>>> exit()

python manage.py shell
>>> from authentication.models import Account
>>> a = Account.objects.all()[0]
>>> a.is_active
False
```

**Updated:** Here is my Account class. The `activateUser()` function above is from the `AccountManager` class which is inherited from `BaseUserManager` and is managing the Account class.

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    """
    Create a new model from AbstractBaseUser account to have our own fields
    """
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)

    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = False

    objects = AccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.firstName + ' ' + self.lastName

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.firstName
```

Comment: "By default, I override the `is_active` field to be False."...can you explain, and/or post your user model?

Comment: Also, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Wtower I don't like the default django user/admin thing, so I just want to rewrite it on my own. Also, I will add more fields later on when needed

Comment: Doesn't have to do with your question, but you should be consistent on what coding style you're using. Now you're mixing camelCase with underscores, in the same model, which looks bad. [Underscores is the convention for Python/Django.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style)

Comment: @ChristofferKarlsson yea, I personally like camelCase better than snake_case, but I guess I will change all to snake_case in python now. The reason why I have both of them is I'm overriding some fields in the base class which are declared in snake_case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nowhere to save `is_active` to, since you haven't assigned a database field to it.

You should change the `is_active` in your model to:

```
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: @mevius Ohhh yea, I totally forgot that :)

Answer (score 1):

In your Account model, change the is_active field definition to:

```
    is_active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_("active"), default=False)
```